# Filter TableView using Query from other View

Tags: ios, uitableview, filter, parse-platform

I want to filter data in my TableView by using switch. I am using Parse. Let`s say I have a TableViewController and a FilterViewController(normal ViewController class). I want to filter data by putting some of switch on. And show filtered TableView after push Done button. I already have some idea, but I do not know how to set the change in TableViewController.

Thanks

[image]

**Filter.h**

```
@protocol ViewControllerDelegate;

@interface FiltrViewController : UIViewController

    {
        IBOutlet UISwitch *switch1;
        IBOutlet UISwitch *switch2;
        IBOutlet UISwitch *switch3;
        IBOutlet UISwitch *switch4;
        IBOutlet UISwitch *switch5;
        IBOutlet UISwitch *switch6;
        IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *button1;
        IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    }

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject *obj;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *keys;
+ (void) filter:(id<ViewControllerDelegate>)delegate;


-(IBAction)buttontouched:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)switch1:(id)sender;

@end

@protocol ViewControllerDelegate < NSObject>

-(void)filter;


@end
```

**Filter.m**

```
@interface FiltrViewController (){
NSMutableDictionary* configG;
}
@property (retain) NSMutableDictionary* configG;

@end


@implementation FiltrViewController

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize configG;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        configG = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)filter
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Countries"];

    NSArray *keys = @[ @"Africa", @"Europe", @"South America", @"North America", @"Asia", @"Australia" ];
    NSArray *defaultValues = @[ @YES, @YES, @YES, @YES, @YES, @YES ];
    NSMutableDictionary *config = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:defaultValues forKeys:keys];



    NSSet *filter = [config keysOfEntriesPassingTest:
                      ^BOOL (id key, NSNumber *value, BOOL *stop) {
                          return [value boolValue];
                      }];


    [query whereKey:@"DescriptTitle" containedIn:[filter allObjects]];

    self.keys = keys;
    self.configG = config;

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    }

-(IBAction)buttontouched:(id)sender;
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    [delegate filter];
        }



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)switch1:(UISwitch *)sender
{

    [self.configG setObject:@([sender isOn]) forKey:[self.keys objectAtIndex:sender.tag]];

}

@end
```

**TableView.m**

```
- (void)FilterTable:(FiltrViewController *)viewController didChooseValue:(CGFloat)value {

   [FiltrViewController filter:self];

}
```

filter method

```
- (void)filterController:(FilterViewController *)controller didEditConfig:(NSMutableDictionary *)config
{
    NSSet *filter = [config keysOfEntriesPassingTest:
                     ^BOOL (id key, NSNumber *value, BOOL *stop) {



                         return [value boolValue];
                     }];


    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Countries"];
    [query whereKey:@"DescriptTitle" containedIn:[filter allObjects]];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {


            //How can I pass filtered objects  from Filter.m back into my TableView?



            [self.MainTable reloadData];

            NSLog(@"%u", objects.count);

        }else{
        }
    }
     ];
```

Comment: `buttontouched:` is called when you are happy with the selection of buttons and `switch1:` is called as each switch is changed?

Comment: Yes and then I have 6 IBActions named switch1,switch2 etc. for [query whereKey:@"DescriptTitle" equalTo:@"Africa"], equalTo:@"Europe"] etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you don't want to run multiple queries in the background each time any switch is changed. Instead, you should keep a configuration of the switch state (I guess you already have this somewhere so you can set the initial state of the switches).

Now, when each switch changes, update the config. When the done button is pressed, send the config back to the other view controller (or save to the shared store / location).

In the other view controller, check if there was a change. If there was, make a new query. But...

Make only 1 query. Set the query class as you are, but add the names of the countries to include as part of that query:

```
// create array of the country names to include
NSArray *countries = ...;

[query whereKey:@"DescriptTitle" containedIn:countries];
```

Now things are much more efficient and easy to handle (one request and one response).

---

**Config:**

You have a set of countries, and you want to be able to enable / disable them. A simple configuration for this is to have a dictionary where the keys are the country names and the values are `NSNumber` instances containing the associated `BOOL` status value.

When you're setting up your switches you can use the values to set the state. And then you can change the state when the switches are toggled.

When done, I would use a delegate relationship to pass the modified config back to the source view controller (your table view controller). (*Note: usually the delegate would dismiss the filter view controller too...*).

To get the list of countries for your query, look at using `keysOfEntriesPassingTest:`.

---

Setup:

```
NSArray *keys = @[ @"Africa", @"Europe", @"South America", @"North America", @"Asia", @"Australia" ];
NSArray *defaultValues = @[ @YES, @YES, @YES, @YES, @YES, @YES ];
NSMutableDictionary *config = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:defaultValues forKeys:keys];

self.keys = keys;
self.config = config;
```

Search (`filter` method):

```
NSSet *filter = [Dictionary keysOfEntriesPassingTest:
                 ^BOOL (id key, NSNumber *value, BOOL *stop) {
                     return [value boolValue];
                 }];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Countries"];
[query whereKey:@"DescriptTitle" containedIn:[filter allObjects]];

// execute the query...
```

Switch change:

-- assuming that the switches have a tag which is the index into the `keys` array

```
- (IBAction)switchChanged:(UISwitch *)sender
{
    [self.config setObject:@([sender isOn]) forKey:[self.keys objectAtIndex:sender.tag]];
}
```

Done button pushed:

```
[self filter];
```

Comment: I still don`t understand to config of switch. Can you describe me little bit more the relations between switch-ViewController-TableView? In some code if it`s possible

Comment: Thanks. I am gonna take a look at it.

Comment: Could you tell me some first lines how to use if else statements in keysOfEntriesPassingTest method. And how does XCode recognize that for example [NSNumber numberWithInt:1] is equal to switch1? I edited my question

Comment: Your keys and objects are the wrong way round - country names should be keys. Don't use `if else`, just use `return [obj boolValue];`. Your value numbers should be `[NSNumber numberWithBOOL:YES]` to turn them all on.

Comment: Can you please edit my code in my question, please. I really don`t know how to do it without if else. I will be your big debtor. Thanks

Comment: Change `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:keys forKeys:objects];` and `containedIn:[filter allObjects]`

Comment: I already made delegate but if I put some switch on, I get error. Sorry but I am really lost with this one

Comment: No idea what your delegate is. Added code to my answer. Do you understand the idea I'm going for? You have a config. The switches change the config. Triggering a query uses just the config.

Comment: Yes, now I understand what did you mean. Thanks. But not sure, if I can express it in my code

Comment: You can use that code, you just need to put it in the right places (and delete some bits you have).

Comment: I tried to remake it, but after I hit the button `Done`, I get no response. TableView is still the same. Could you please tell me, where the problem is?

Comment: Hey Wain, do you have a minute for me now?

Comment: Wain, may I ask you one more question? Can you join chat for a minute. Thank you

Comment: Wain, I finally fixed probs with passing keys and config into filter.m, but I can`t find the right method how to add filtered data back into my tableview. Could you give me some thread. I posted my final filter code upside. Thanks a lot

Comment: Where you have `//How can I pass filtered objects` you need to save `objects` as the array you use to populate the table

Comment: Are you sure with this line? `self.konfiggg setObject:@([sender isOn]) forKey:[self.kejsss objectAtIndex:sender.tag]];`, I am getting error here after put switch on/off

Comment: Wain, could you join chat for one more time? I wanna talk you about that airpair. Thanks